# How to get Latitude Longitude value without using GPS in Android?

Tags: android

I have a device which has no GPS module. Is there any way to get the Lat Lon value without using the GPS module in Android.

Hey, down voters can you explain what is wrong in this question?
If you have a Answer to the question the give otherwise try to understand the questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put below Java class in your package.

**MyLocation.java**

```
    import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try
        {
            gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() 
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);



          //  lm.removeUpdates(this);
            //lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener()
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
           // lm.removeUpdates(this);
         //   lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             //lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             //lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult
    {
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

Now, in your activity you can find the location as like below code:

```
    public static Location loc;

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);

        // to Find the Location 
        LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
            @Override
            public void gotLocation(final Location location){
                loc=location;
                System.out.println("Latitude: "+loc.getLatitude());
                System.out.println("Longitude: "+loc.getLongitude());
            }
        };

        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
    myLocation.getLocation(SplashActivity.this, locationResult);
    }
}
```

With above code you dont have to on the GPS in device. It will automatically check for the best available locationmanager and find location based on it.

it also required some permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I get a NullPointerException thrown for the loc variable. Any idea why this is? `FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0` is also displayed.

Comment: at which line you get NPE. as it is working nice for my case

Comment: found location null if my gps is not on

Answer (score 5):

If your Device don't have GPS then you can also use Network_Provider for get latitude and longitude, Use below code for get latitude and longitude using Network_Provider, it will solve your problem.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) GlobalApplication
            .getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Location location = lm
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

if(location != null){
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

Comment: it gives null at location variable... my gps is not on and I want long and lat to be found with out gps..

Comment: It gives me location null

Answer (score 2):

```
    Location location =myManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    latPoint=location.getLatitude();
    lngPoint=location.getLongitude();
```

hope this will help you.
here we are getting latitude and longitude using network provider not using GPS.thats what u wanted.

Comment: it gives me location null so cant find latitude and longitude