# How to get Latitude and Longitude without using GPS?

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

I want to get Latitude and Longitude from my android application, without GPS. 
is there any way? I saw a tutorial here (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_location_based_services.htm) but i can't make an object of LocationClient as said in that tutorial. i also installed Google Play Service Sdk into my Application, even though i can't create an instance of LocationClient.

Comment: check out this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761367/how-to-get-latitute-longitude-value-without-using-gps-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this

you can get location without using GPS

[Fused location provider](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html)

Comment: That was an helpful one.

Answer (score 1):

Use This code

```
private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, lat+"" + lng +" ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

put following line into onCreate()

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,10000,
                1, mLocationListener);
```